# GFCI outlets easily trip

Tags: electrical

Both kitchen counter GFCI outlets trip quite easily when plugging in small appliances. One also trips, maybe once a month or so, as the coffeemaker tries to make coffee. This has been going on for years through several different coffeemakers. Both GFCI outlets have a single branch outlet downstream. I wired the entire house as part of my renovation project and it passed inspection. I've gone over my wiring and GFCI outlet wiring instructions and used a GFCI circuit tester and it all seems to be correct. This has annoyed my wife and I for a long time now. Hope someone has suggestions on how to dig deeper into this.

Comment: How old are the GFI plugs? Are they of decent quality?
I've had cheaper GFIs get overly sensitive after just a couple years.
I've since upgraded to better GFIs and have had much better results.

Also, check to make sure there isn't another GFI on the circuit somewhere that could be making them trip easy.

Comment: Leviton 20A GFCIs; don't know how they rate, but thought they were considered decent at the time. I installed them about 19 years ago when I rewired the house. Each of the GFCI outliets are wired directly to their own dedicated standard SquareD Homeline 20A circuit breaker; just one downstream GFCI-protected standard outlet for each. All wired with 12/2.

Comment: Do any of these appliances have 3-prong plugs?  Are any appliances left plugged in 24x7?  Would you be able to pull the GFCI out, unhook the LINE wires, and do some ohmmeter measurements?

Comment: newer GFCIs work better than old ones. not sure if that's a design issue or an aging issue, but it seems to be the case.

Comment: 19 years is a bit old for GFCI outlets anyway.

Comment: The coffeemaker is plugged in 24/7 using a programmed timer to fire up in the morning; it has a ground in the plug. Most of the other appliances don't have a ground. I've turned off both breakers and have a VOM and tools on the counter...

Comment: With the power off, on each of the GFCI's I'd like you to unhook the wires from LINE. Then go to the other receptacle controlled by that GFCI and take 2 resistance measurements:  Ground to neutral.   And ground to hot.    You can test other locations too, really anywhere that number is under a megaohm I'd like to know about it.

Comment: The next test is to get one of those 3/2 prong ["cheaters"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cheater_plug) (they cost about a dollar), insulate the little metal ground tab, and plug the coffeemaker through it, intentionally making the coffeemaker not grounded.  (this is sane because there is a GFCI protecting it).  Do the trips go away?